# Shifting from chatbot view to ionic mobile app page automatically when reaching a step in dialogue flow

Tags: c#, angular, ionic3, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using MS chatbot-framework V3 and embedding it in my ionic 3 mobile app via **Direct line**.

What I am aiming to is when reaching the end of conversation, the chatbot is terminated and shifting to another page in the mobile app with passing some values from chatbot to that page.

Comment: How are you connecting to he bot in your app? Did you embed Web Chat, or did you build a custom chat interface using DirectLine?

Comment: I hope you got it working! If you feel my answer was sufficient, please "accept" it so I can clear this ticket from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the end of your conversation, you can send an event activity to your DirectLine Client with channel data from the conversation, and once the client receives the event, you can transition to the next view in your app with the channel data.  See the code snippets below.

**Sending Transition Event**

In the bot, we are going to send back channel events to DirectLine with the data we have gathered in the chat. Basically, you just need to send an activity with the type property set to 'event' and the name attribute set to some string value - we are going to use 'transition' in this case. The conversation data is going to be encapsulated in the activity's channel data.

```cs
// End of conversation 

var reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();

reply.Name = "transition";
reply.Type = "event";
reply.ChannelData = JObject.FromObject( new {
    user = new {
        name = "TJ",
        location = "Seattle"
    }
});

await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

**Listen for Transition Event**

On the client side, we are going to filter the incoming activities to listen for our 'transition' event from the bot. When it's received, you can transition to the next view and pass along the channel data which contains the conversation data.

```
import { DirectLine } from 'botframework-directlinejs';

var directLine = new DirectLine({
    secret: "<DIRECTLINE_SECRET"
});

directLine.activity$
  .filter(activity => activity.type === 'event' && activity.name === 'transition')
  .subscribe( activity => { /* Initiate transition to next view with activity.channelData */ });
```

Hope this helps!